# Using aggregate function

Tags: sql, db2

```
select 
    o.ORDERS_ID,
    o.TOTALPRODUCT,
    o.TOTALADJUSTMENT,
    sum(o.TOTALPRODUCT+o.TOTALADJUSTMENT) as Paid_Total_orders,
    p.APPROVEDAMOUNT 

from 
    orders o, 
    ppcpayinst p 

where 
    o.orders_id=p.order_id 
    and sum(o.TOTALPRODUCT+o.TOTALADJUSTMENT)!= p.APPROVEDAMOUNT 

group by 
    o.orders_id,
    o.TOTALPRODUCT,
    o.TOTALADJUSTMENT,
    p.APPROVEDAMOUNT"
```

Error:

> SQL0120N  Invalid use of an aggregate function or OLAP function.
>   SQLSTATE=42903

can some please correct my query

Comment: There's something very fishy about this query. `Orders_ID` is most likely a unique field on the `Orders` table, so why would you be `SUM`ing other fields from the `Orders` table.

Comment: Please don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause), always explicitly state your joins.  What version of DB2?  What are your data relations like (ie, 1-to-1, 1-to-many), and can we get some sample data?

Answer (score 4):

**The other answers are correct about why you're seeing this error, but I strongly suspect you are going about this whole query the wrong way.**

I think it is much more likely you're just trying to do this:

```
SELECT 
    o.ORDERS_ID,
    o.TOTALPRODUCT,
    o.TOTALADJUSTMENT,
    o.TOTALPRODUCT+o.TOTALADJUSTMENT as Paid_Total_orders,
    p.APPROVEDAMOUNT 
FROM 
    orders o, 
    ppcpayinst p 
WHERE 
    o.orders_id=p.order_id 
    and o.TOTALPRODUCT+o.TOTALADJUSTMENT != p.APPROVEDAMOUNT
```

If my suspicions are correct then the other query will give you exactly the same result, but whilst doing lots of illogical `GROUP`ing where you're just grouping single rows together and `SUM`ing up single values.

I can't think of a single reason why you would ever need to `GROUP BY` every field from every table you are `SELECT`ing from and use an aggregate at the same time.

If I am incorrect then I apologise, but I think this is very likely the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use an aggregate function in WHERE clause, since those are only calculated after a GROUP BY. That's the job for HAVING :

```
select 
    o.ORDERS_ID,
    o.TOTALPRODUCT,
    o.TOTALADJUSTMENT,
    sum(o.TOTALPRODUCT+o.TOTALADJUSTMENT) as Paid_Total_orders,
    p.APPROVEDAMOUNT     
from 
    orders o, 
    ppcpayinst p     
where 
    o.orders_id=p.order_id 
group by 
    o.orders_id,
    o.TOTALPRODUCT,
    o.TOTALADJUSTMENT,
    p.APPROVEDAMOUNT
HAVING sum(o.TOTALPRODUCT+o.TOTALADJUSTMENT)!= p.APPROVEDAMOUNT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    o.ORDERS_ID,
    o.TOTALPRODUCT,
    o.TOTALADJUSTMENT,
    sum(o.TOTALPRODUCT+o.TOTALADJUSTMENT) as Paid_Total_orders,
    p.APPROVEDAMOUNT 

from orders o INNER JOIN  ppcpayinst p 
ON o.orders_id=p.order_id
group by 
    o.orders_id,
    o.TOTALPRODUCT,
    o.TOTALADJUSTMENT,
    p.APPROVEDAMOUNT
HAVING  sum(o.TOTALPRODUCT+o.TOTALADJUSTMENT)!= p.APPROVEDAMOUNT
```

**WHERE Vs HAVING**

filter/Condition used in where clause filter the rows even before any aggregate function is applied on the returned rows.

Having Clause filters the rows after the aggregates has been done.